# Причастный оборот, не имеющий определяемого слова

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос по поводу причастного оборота. Выделяется ли причастный оборот, не имеющий определяемого слова? Как, например, в «Провел 50 часов(,) погребенный заживо», «Желаю радости(,) читающему этот комментарий», «Не повторяйте дома(,) увиденное в этом видео». И есть ли случаи, когда причастные обороты без главного слова обособляются, а когда нет? Если есть, то какие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое предложение является неполным от предложения: ‟Я провёл 50 часов погребённый заживо”, и в данном случае определяемое слово есть, но оно пропущено в неполном. Определение не обособляется по [этому пункту (пункт 10, подпункт 2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)  из справочника Розенталя, где сказано, что определение не обособляется, если может быть заменено таким же определением, но с творительным падежом, – например, предложение: ‟Я нашёл его готового пуститься в дорогу” – можно заменить на предложение: ‟Я нашёл его готовым пуститься в дорогу”.

Что касается двух других предложений, то это просто субстантивы – когда прилагательное или причастие употребляется без определяемого слова и начинает обозначать то же, что и существительные. Вот несколько примеров предложений с субстантивами: ‟Худеющим живётся не легко”, ‟В комнату вошёл толстый”, ‟Увиденное потрясло меня”. Субстантивы не обособляются запятыми.